# Is there something named "Tales of the Dark Forest" from before 2009, that involves unicorns?

Tags: story-identification, unicorns

A quick search inside Archive.org's copies of Steve Barlow's book series of the name, doesn't have any mention of "Unicorn" across any of the four books.

1. [Knyghtmare](https://archive.org/details/knyghtmare0000barl)
2. [Goodknyght](https://archive.org/details/goodknyght0000barl)
3. [Trollogy](https://archive.org/details/trollogy0000barl)
4. [Whizzard](https://archive.org/details/whizzard0000barl)

But TVTropes has twice mentioned some work of the name, that *does* involve unicorns, but calls it Anime or maybe Manga or maybe a work in English, but if they *are* talking about the same work, [it's unclear](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/posts.php?discussion=13327285370A47480700):

[Ascended To Carnivorism](https://tvtropes.org/Main/AscendedToCarnivorism), which was on the page from before 2009:

> a half-crazy unicorn decides that if he eats the corpse of a human, he can gain human powers, including a digestive tract that can handle meat.

[Virginity Makes You Stupid](https://tvtropes.org/Main/VirginityMakesYouStupid):

> Subverted with the manga-esque series *Tales of the Dark Forest*. Virgins have to be smart so they can outwit and kill the unicorns they stay virgins in order to hunt. The reason it's a subversion is that the first virgin we see in the series is used for unicorn bait, and really is that naively stupid at least until she's on the run with and apprenticed to a real unicorn huntress. Then again, she did arrange for said huntress' deflowering beforehand.

Comment: So I did a quick search around a couple-three comics databases and manga databases, plus ISFDb, amazon and worldcat.  I can't find anything by that name _except_ Barlow's books.  It wouldn't be the first time there's made-up stuff in TVTropes.

Comment: @DavidW - Indeed. A lot of their references seem to be completely invented nonsense

Comment: As far as I know, unverifiable work pages and examples get cut down as unpublished, like what happened to Vresun Ciraian Ruins and the Complete Monster writeup for The Locust, so you should delete any spurious examples when you see them.